# How would you write a method that takes 2 String array and sort the elements in the array by how long each element is?

Tags: java

How would you write a  method that takes 2 string arrays and merges them into one array in order by the length of each element in the array by using mergeSort. And by using compareToIgnoreCase?

This is the code that I have so far. I dont even know if im doing it right so far; I'm just trying to make my merge sort work.

```
public static String[] merge(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    String index1 = "";
    String index2 = "";
    String[] result = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

    while (index1 < arr1.length && index2 < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[index1] < arr2[index2]) {
            result[index1 + index2] = arr1[index1];
            index1++;
        } else {
            result[index1 + index2] = arr2[index2];
            index2++;               
        }
    }

    if (index1 == arr1.length){
        for (String i = index2; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            result[index1 + i] = arr2[i];
        }
    } else if (index2 == arr2.length){
        for (String i = index1; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            result[index2 + i] = arr1[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you even compiled the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really literal code snippet that answers your question.  It uses a merge sort algorithm to combine two string arrays (must merge sort each individually first) into one sorted array.  The comparisons are done based on length first (smaller entries before larger entries) and then by using compareToIgnoreCase.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {

    // How would you write a method that takes 2 string arrays and merges them
    // into one array in order by the length of each element in the array by
    // using mergeSort. And by using compareToIgnoreCase?

    private static Comparator<String> COMP = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1.length() < o2.length()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if(o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    };

    public static String[] mergeUnsorted(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        arr1 = sort(arr1);
        arr2 = sort(arr2);

        return merge(arr1, arr2);
    }

    private static String[] sort(String[] arr) {
        if(arr.length <= 1)
            return arr;

        String[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length/2);
        String[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length/2, arr.length);

        left = sort(left);
        right = sort(right);

        String[] combined = merge(left, right);

        return combined;
    }

    private static String[] merge(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        String[] combined = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

        int a = 0, b = 0, i = 0;

        while(a < arr1.length || b < arr2.length) {
            int compare = 0;
            if(a >= arr1.length) {
                compare = 1;
            } else if(b >= arr2.length) {
                compare = -1;
            } else {
                compare = COMP.compare(arr1[a], arr2[b]);
            }

            if(compare < 0) {
                combined[i] = arr1[a];
                i++;
                a++;
            } else if(compare > 0) {
                combined[i] = arr2[b];
                i++;
                b++;
            } else {
                combined[i] = arr1[a];
                i++;
                a++;
                combined[i] = arr2[b];
                i++;
                b++;
            }
        }

        return combined;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr1 = new String[] { "abc", "a", "A", "bA", "Ba" };
        String[] arr2 = new String[] { "def", "d", "D", "fG", "Fg", "abcde", "B" };

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeUnsorted(arr1, arr2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sorting you should use ArrayList. ArrayList provide sort method for String. No need to implement your custom sorting.

Further more if you want to sort your  own objects Collection provide the facility  to sort them using Comparable and Comparator.

```
 List<String> ls1=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ls2=new ArrayList<String>();
    ls1.addAll(ls2);
    Collections.sort(ls1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First, `index1` and `index2` should be `int` values instead of `String` values. Second, you cannot compare strings using `<`; use `String.compareTo()` or `String.compareToIgnoreCase()`. If you want to compare string lengths, then use something like `if (arr1[index1].length() < arr2[index2].length()) { ...`.

Otherwise, I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following step:

1. merge two array(or more array) by `ArrayUtile` in [Apache Commons Lang3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).
2. define a custom `Comparatore` interface for implementing ignore case.
3. sort merged array by `Arrays` utilitin `java.util`.

I write this code as utility method:

```
public void sort(String[] one, String[] two)
{
    String[] merged_array = ArrayUtils.addAll(one, two);

    Comparator<String> ignorCase_comparatore = new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1,
                           String o2)
        {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    };

    Arrays.sort(merged_array, ignorCase_comparatore);
}
```

I hope my answer useful for you.

Comment: doesnt this need more coding like dont you need to insert merge sort somewhere and is there another way instead of using ArrayUtils because I dont really understand that very well.

Comment: above code is short and readable, You don't need implement `merge` operation yourself.